# Weblogic integrated server instance cannot be started from jdeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

I have installed Oracle SOA Suite QuickStart (12.2.1.4.0) in Windows 7.
The Java version I'm using is jdk1.8.0_241.

When I tried to start the integrated server instance from JDeveloper, I got this error message:

> The Server Instance cannot be started because the IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain was not built successfully.

In the BuildDefaultDomain.log file, I saw the following error:

> ERROR: Unable to locate property "JAVA_HOME" in properties file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oui\bin...globalEnv.properties

I have also set JAVA_HOME environment variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241.

BuildDefaultDomain.log

```
Adding environment variable to WLST script USER_MEM_ARGS = -Xms32m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
Log File:      C:\Users\10064270\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain.log
Label:         JDEVADF_PT.12.2.1.4.0_GENERIC_190911.2248.S
Product Home:  C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\
Domain:        C:\Users\10064270\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\DefaultDomain

BuildDefaultDomain1.py      2020-03-30 10:17:12

cmd.exe /c ""C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\10064270\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py""
Process started
wlst > The system cannot find the file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oui\bin\..\.globalEnv.properties.
wlst > ERROR: Unable to locate property "JAVA_HOME" in properties file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oui\bin\..\.globalEnv.properties
wlst > 
wlst > Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
wlst > 
wlst > Mar 30, 2020 10:17:20 AM com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl init
wlst > SEVERE: Failed to get inventory for C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home
wlst > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.common.ReflectionHelper.process(ReflectionHelper.java:48)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl.init(EnvironmentServiceImpl.java:384)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl.<init>(EnvironmentServiceImpl.java:89)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceImpl.getInstance(EnvironmentServiceImpl.java:364)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceFactory.getEnvironmentService(EnvironmentServiceFactory.java:35)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.env.EnvironmentServiceFactory.getEnvironmentService(EnvironmentServiceFactory.java:72)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.init(WLScriptContext.java:306)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLScriptContext.setup(WLScriptContext.java:273)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython.WLST_offline.setupContext(WLST_offline.java:46)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.initOfflineContext(WLSTUtil.java:514)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.setupOfflineInternal(WLSTUtil.java:488)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtil.setupOffline(WLSTUtil.java:361)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtilWrapper.setupOffline(WLSTUtilWrapper.java:29)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter.<init>(WLSTInterpreter.java:250)
wlst >  at weblogic.management.scripting.WLST.main(WLST.java:134)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wlst >  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wlst >  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wlst >  at weblogic.WLST.main(WLST.java:47)
wlst > Caused by: com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.InventoryException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate file distributions\SOA_QuickStart_12.2.1.4.0.xml under lookup locations [C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\inventory]
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.impl.OracleHomeInventoryImpl.<init>(OracleHomeInventoryImpl.java:65)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.impl.OracleHomeInventoryFactory.createInventory(OracleHomeInventoryFactory.java:60)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.InventoryFactory.getOracleHomeInventory(InventoryFactory.java:99)
wlst >  ... 28 more
wlst > Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate file distributions\SOA_QuickStart_12.2.1.4.0.xml under lookup locations [C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\inventory]
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.services.FileLocatorService.getPath(FileLocatorService.java:303)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DistributionHelper.getDistribution(DistributionHelper.java:300)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DistributionHelper.getDistribution(DistributionHelper.java:242)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.DistributionLoader.<init>(DistributionLoader.java:92)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.DistributionLoaderFactory.getDistributionLoader(DistributionLoaderFactory.java:45)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.loadInstalledDistributions(Home.java:1834)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.loadInstalledMetaData(Home.java:1357)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.loadHomeMetaData(Home.java:1338)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.refresh(Home.java:1279)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.setHome(Home.java:378)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.<init>(Home.java:346)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.getHome(Home.java:279)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.getHome(Home.java:242)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.Home.getHome(Home.java:191)
wlst >  at com.oracle.cie.gdr.external.impl.OracleHomeInventoryImpl.<init>(OracleHomeInventoryImpl.java:60)
wlst >  ... 30 more
wlst >
```

Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs if you have no permission to accsess the file "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oui.globalEnv.properties". If you have installed JDeveloper as administrator and run it as normal user, by default you have no access to this file.

So you need to run jdev as admin and then try to start the instance

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. The issue was with the lack of permission to access the ‍‍‍
`C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oui\bin...globalEnv.properties`
file. Only with admin access, I was able to start the instance smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Windows Desktop 7 or 10 is not supported for this product. Please review the supported systems matrix, [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/fmw-122140-certmatrix-5763476.xlsx).
2. I have successfully installed SOA Suite 12c 12.2.1.4 on Windows 10. I have never tried 7 and would not as support ended for it this year, [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information).
   One thing you could try is (re)installing into a directory with *no spaces* in the names. E.g. do not use "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241" Try installing the JDK and the Oracle software to a different location, like c:\java for the jdk and c:\oracle\middleware  for soa.

NOTE - I DO NOT recommend installing application software to the root of the C drive. This is simply an example. I always use a second drive D: to install my Oracle software, etc. However, this is not required, and if one only has a C: drive then I would install as indicated in #2 above.

Lastly please consider going to [My Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com/portal/) and searching there for the specific error.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows set the Java home in a directory without white space.
In this way you should resolve your issue